# Op type not registered HashTableV2 in Tensorflow 1.4.1 while deploying in Cloud ML

Tags: tensorflow, text-classification, tensorflow-serving, google-cloud-ml

When we deploying the model to cloud ml we are getting **Bad model Op type not registered HashTableV2**

**Code:**

```
def model_fn(features, labels, mode):
if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
    tf.keras.backend.set_learning_phase(True)
else:
    tf.keras.backend.set_learning_phase(False)

input_feature = features['x']
table = lookup.index_table_from_file(vocabulary_file='vocab.txt', num_oov_buckets=1, default_value=-1)
text = tf.squeeze(input_feature, [1])
words = tf.string_split(text)
dense_words = tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(words, default_value=PADWORD)
numbers = table.lookup(dense_words)
padding = tf.constant([[0, 0], [0, MAX_LEN]])
padded = tf.pad(numbers, padding)
sliced = tf.slice(padded, [0, 0], [-1, MAX_LEN])
print('words_sliced={}'.format(words))

embeds = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(MAX_FEATURES+1, 128, input_length=MAX_LEN)(sliced)

print('words_embed={}'.format(embeds))
f1 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(embeds)
f1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters, kernel_size, padding='valid', activation='relu', strides=1)(f1)
f1 = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D()(f1)
f1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(hidden_dims)(f1)
f1 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(f1)
f1 = tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu')(f1)
logits = tf.keras.layers.Dense(11)(f1)

predictions_dict = {
    'class': tf.argmax(logits, 1),
    'prob': tf.nn.softmax(logits)
}

'''prediction_output = tf.estimator.export.PredictOutput({"classes": tf.argmax(input=logits, axis=1),
                                                       "probabilities": tf.nn.softmax(logits,
                                                                                      name="softmax_tensor")})'''

if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, predictions=predictions_dict, export_outputs={
        'prediction': tf.estimator.export.PredictOutput(predictions_dict)
    })

loss = tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy(labels, logits=logits)

if mode == tf.contrib.learn.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
    train_op = tf.contrib.layers.optimize_loss(loss, tf.contrib.framework.get_global_step(), optimizer='Adam',
                                               learning_rate=0.001)
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, loss=loss, train_op=train_op)

eval_metrics_ops = {
    'accuracy': tf.metrics.accuracy(labels=labels, predictions=predictions_dict['class']),
    'precision': tf.metrics.precision(labels=labels, predictions=predictions_dict['class']),
    'recall': tf.metrics.recall(labels=labels, predictions=predictions_dict['class'])
}
return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, loss=loss, eval_metric_ops=eval_metrics_ops)

def get_train_record(record):
    vector = tf.decode_csv(record, DEFAULTS, use_quote_delim=True)
    return vector[1:], vector[0]

def preprocess(text):
    text = text.lower()
    result = ' '.join([word for word in text.split() if word not in (stop_words)])
    return result


def build_vocab(file_name, vocab_file_name):
    df = pd.read_csv(file_name, header=None, sep=',', skiprows=[1], names=['product', 'consumer_complaint_narrative'])
    df['consumer_complaint_narrative'] = df['consumer_complaint_narrative'].apply(preprocess)
    print(df['consumer_complaint_narrative'][0])
    vocab_processor = tflearn.preprocessing.VocabularyProcessor(max_document_length=MAX_FEATURES, min_frequency=10,
                                                                tokenizer_fn=tflearn.preprocessing.tokenizer)
    vocab_processor.fit(df['consumer_complaint_narrative'])
    with gfile.Open(vocab_file_name, 'wb') as f:
        f.write("{}\n".format(PADWORD))
        for word, index in vocab_processor.vocabulary_._mapping.items():
            f.write("{}\n".format(word))
    nwords = len(vocab_processor.vocabulary_)
    print('{} words into {}'.format(nwords, vocab_file_name))


def input_fn(file_name, batch_size, repeat_count, shuffle=False):
    def _input_fn():
        data_set = tf.data.TextLineDataset(filenames=file_name)
        data_set = data_set.map(get_train_record)
        if shuffle:
            data_set = data_set.shuffle(shuffle)
        data_set = data_set.repeat(repeat_count)
        batch = data_set.batch(batch_size)
        iterator = batch.make_one_shot_iterator()
        features, labels = iterator.get_next()
        return {'x': features}, labels

    return _input_fn()


def get_train_spec(file_name, batch_size, repeat_count):
    return tf.estimator.TrainSpec(input_fn=lambda: input_fn(file_name, batch_size, repeat_count, shuffle=True), max_steps=1000)


def get_test_spec(file_name, batch_size, repeat_count=1):
    return tf.estimator.EvalSpec(input_fn=lambda: input_fn(file_name, batch_size, repeat_count, shuffle=True))


def serving_input_fn():
    feature_tensor = tf.placeholder(tf.string, [None])
    # features = tf.py_func(preprocess, [feature_tensor], tf.string)
    features = tf.expand_dims(feature_tensor, -1)
    return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver({'x': features}, {'x': features})

finance_classifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=model_fn, model_dir=model_dir)

print('\n Training .....')
finance_classifier.train(input_fn=lambda: input_fn('dataset/train.csv', batch_size, repeat_count=5, shuffle=True))

print('\n Evaluating.....')
eval_results = finance_classifier.evaluate(input_fn=lambda: input_fn('dataset/valid.csv', batch_size, repeat_count=1,
                                                                  shuffle=False))
for key in eval_results:
    print(" {} was {}".format(key, eval_results[key]))

print('\n Exporting')
exported_model_dir = finance_classifier.export_savedmodel(model_dir, serving_input_receiver_fn=serving_input_fn)
decoded_model_dir = exported_model_dir.decode("utf-8")
```

[Screenshot](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1FAmoo9zCBJBAG2IFdySb_r4s1OV6YExn)

One important thing to mention here is when I tried with Tensorflow 1.2 with some changes in the code in model_fn. Basically not using tf.keras but using tf.contrib.keras it was working.

The model which was exported in Tensorflow 1.2 works fine. Is it a bug in Tensorflow 1.4 ? How can we fix this error ?

Already created a gihub issue in Tensorflow [Repo](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/15525)

Comment: can you share the command you used to deploy the model?

Answer (score 0):

The ML Engine supports TensorFlow 1.4 but the default version is TensorFlow 1.2. You can specify that you want 1.4 by adding the following code to your project's setup.py module:

```
REQUIRED_PACKAGES = ['tensorflow>=1.4']
setup(
...
    install_requires=REQUIRED_PACKAGES,
...
)
```

You can see the full list of supported packages and versions [here](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/runtime-version-list).

Comment: Setting tensorflow>=1.4 will trigger pip install. CloudML Engine is supporting TF 1.4 now, so you can simply specify --runtime-versio=1.4 in gCloud, by which the service will load the TF 1.4 for you.

Answer (score 0):

We can solve this problem by setting **--runtime-version=1.4**.

Use the following command when deploying model in cloud ml.

```
MODEL_BINARIES=$(gsutil ls gs://${BUCKET}/models/${MODEL_NAME}/export/)

gcloud ml-engine versions create ${MODEL_VERSION} --model=${MODEL_NAME} --origin=${MODEL_BINARIES} --runtime-version=1.4
```